# how splitBetween method works

Tags: flutter, dart

```
List integerList=[1,2,4,11,14,15,16,16,19,30,31,50,51,100,101,105]; //input


var subList=integerList.splitBetween((v1, v2) => (v2 - v1).abs() > 6);
print(subList); //([1, 2, 4], [11, 14, 15, 16, 16, 19], [30, 31], [50, 51], [100, 101, 105])
```

what is the logic **splitBetween** methods works here ?

Comment: if `(v2 - v1).abs() > 6` is `true` then your input list is divided between items `v1` and `v2`, if it is `false` nothing happens

Comment: yes! yes but how initially chose v1 and v2 as input, how it's iteration works

Comment: press `Ctrl` key and click left mouse button on `splitBeteeen` method and you will see the sources

Answer (score 1):

check each pair of adjacent elements `v1` and `v2`

lets use your data:

```
[1,2,4,11,14,15,16,16,19,30,31,50,51,100,101,105]
```

begin with index 0 and 1

- we have : `v1 = 1` , `v2 = 2`
- then test with the function `(v2 - v1).abs() > 6)`
- `( 1-2).abs()>6 = false`

---

index 1 and 2 : `v1=2` , `v2=4`

- `(2 -4).abs() > 6 = false`

---

index 2 and 3 : `v1=4` , `v2=11`

- `(4 - 11).abs() > 6` `absolute(-7) > 6 = true`,
- since its true : **the elements since the previous chunk-splitting elements are emitted as a list**

which means, index 1 - 3 emmited as a list.

- current `sublist = ([1,2,4])`

---

and so on

- index : 4 - 8 is false. and pair of index 8 and 9 is true
- current `sublist = ([1,2,4], [11,14,15,16,16,19])`
  repeat untin last index.

lastly :if at last index are false then we keep add to the list. because it says that :  **Any final elements are emitted at the end.**

final result : `([1, 2, 4], [11, 14, 15, 16, 16, 19], [30, 31], [50, 51], [100, 101, 105])`